# Calling two urls for TableView in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have two urls to call to get json object and tabulate them in tableviewcontroller. However, I could not able to figure out how to Create a single TableSource that can handle two different instances of List.

```
public void Inbox()
        {
            var ts= new TableSource(this);
            TableView.Source=ts;

            var client1 = new RestClient ("MyURL");
            client1.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator ("admin", "admin");
            var request1 = new RestRequest ("MYURL/x/y");
            request1.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
            request1.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");


            var client2 = new RestClient ("MyURL");
            client2.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator ("admin", "admin");
            var request2 = new RestRequest ("MYURL/a/b");
            request2.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
            request2.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");

            client1.ExecuteAsync (request1, response1 => {

                aTasks = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HTask>> (response1.Content);

                InvokeOnMainThread (() => {

                    ts.Data1= aTasks;
                    TableView.ReloadData();

                });
            });

            client2.ExecuteAsync (request2, response2 => {
                bTasks = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HTask>> (response2.Content);

                InvokeOnMainThread (() => {

                    ts.Data2= bTasks;
                    TableView.ReloadData();

                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your TableSource and assign it when you create your TableView.  Instead of passing the data in the constructor, create two public properties for the two different datasets you're working with.

```
var ts = new TableSource(this);
TableView.Source = ts;
```

later, then you have your data loaded, update your existing TableSource

```
ts.Data1 = aTasks;
TableView.ReloadData();
```

when your second set of data loads, update your existing TableSource again

```
ts.Data2 = bTasks;
TableView.ReloadData();
```

Comment: Jason, I have updated the code above, is that what you propose?

Comment: Once I run the code posted in the question, it gives unknown iddefier:request1 error

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  If you're getting an "unknown identifier" error that should be simple to find and fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not able to fix the problem.

Comment: Is it a compile error or a runtime error?  "Unknown Identifier" is usually just caused by a typo

Comment: Hello Jason, I have posted full source code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376458/table-section-url-calling-in-xamarin