# Table Section URL Calling in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I would like to display two section tableviewcontroller. I have two urls to call to get json object and tabulate them in tableviewcontroller. I could not able to figure out how to Create a single TableSource that can handle two different instances of List.

I am posting here full source code here. I will be glad if any one able to help me out in this problem, either share a link that would be useful, or share the code.

> ```
>  public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
> ```
>
> returns me an "object reference not set" error. It seems to me that once I fecth data from the first url and it tries to tabulate tableview, however, the other URL data at that time may not be ready.

```
namespace TPM
{
    partial class IViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public List<HumanTask> cTasks;
        public List<HumanTask> aTasks;


        public InboxViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            this.Title = "Inside";
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            GInbox ();
            CInbox ();


        }

        public void CInbox()
        {
            var client = new RestClient ("URL");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator ("admin", "admin");
            var request = new RestRequest ("other part URL");
            request.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");

            client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                cTasks = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HTask>> (response.Content);

                InvokeOnMainThread (() => {

                    TableView.Source= new TableSource(cTasks,this,0);
                    TableView.ReloadData();

                });
            });


        }

        public void GInbox()
        {

            var client = new RestClient ("URL");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator ("admin", "admin");
            var request = new RestRequest ("the rest URL");
            request.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");

            client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                aTasks = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HTask>> (response.Content);

                InvokeOnMainThread (() => {

                    TableView.Source= new TableSource(aTasks,this,1);
                    TableView.ReloadData();

                });
            });
        }

        public class TableSource:UITableViewSource{

            List<HTask>cTableItems;
            List<HTask>aTableItems;
            int defi;
            string cellIdentifier="TableCell";
            private IViewController iv;

            public TableSource (List<HTask>items, IViewController vc, int def)
            {
                if(def==0)
                {
                    cTableItems=items;
                }
                else if(def==1)
                {
                    aTableItems=items;
                }
                iv=vc;
                defi=def;
            }


            public override nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
            {
                return 2;
            }

            public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader (UITableView tableView, nint section)
            {
                if(section==0){
                    return 40;
                }
                if(section == 1) {
                    return 40;
                }

                return 40;

            }

            public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
            {
                UIView headerView = new UIView(new RectangleF (0, 0, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, (float)tableView.SectionHeaderHeight));
                   headerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
                    UILabel sectionTitle = new UILabel( new RectangleF(10, (float)((headerView.Frame.Height - 22) / 2), 200, 24));
                    sectionTitle.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(22);
                    sectionTitle.TextColor = UIColor.White;
                    sectionTitle.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
                    if (section == 0) {
                      sectionTitle.Text = "Cmed";
                     }
                    else if (section == 1) {
                      sectionTitle.Text = "Asy";
                    }
                    headerView.AddSubview(sectionTitle);

                    return headerView;

            }


            public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
            {
                if (section == 0)
                    return cTableItems.Count;
                else 
                    return aTableItems.Count;
            }

            public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);
                if (cell == null)
                    cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);
                if (indexPath.Section == 0) {
                    cell.TextLabel.Text = cTableItems [indexPath.Row].displayName;
                    cell.DetailTextLabel.Lines = 3;
                    cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = "Process ID:" + cTableItems [indexPath.Row].processInstanceId + "\n" + DateTime.Parse (Convert.ToDateTime (cTableItems [indexPath.Row].createdOn).ToShortTimeString ());
                    if (cTableItems [indexPath.Row].priority == 0) {
                        cell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/green.png");
                    }
                    else if (cTableItems [indexPath.Row].priority == 1) {
                        cell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/yellow.png");
                    }
                    else if (cTableItems [indexPath.Row].priority == 2) {
                        cell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/red.png");
                    }

                }
                else if (indexPath.Section == 1) {
                    cell.TextLabel.Text = assignTableItems [indexPath.Row].displayName;
                    cell.DetailTextLabel.Lines = 3;
                    cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = "Process ID:" + aTableItems [indexPath.Row].processInstanceId + "\n" + DateTime.Parse (Convert.ToDateTime (aTableItems [indexPath.Row].createdOn).ToShortTimeString ());

                    if (aTableItems [indexPath.Row].priority == 0) {
                        cell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/green.png");
                    }
                    else if (aTableItems [indexPath.Row].priority == 1) {
                        cell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/yellow.png");
                    }
                    else if (aTableItems [indexPath.Row].priority == 2) {
                        cell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/red.png");
                    }
                }

                cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

                return cell;
            }

            public override nfloat GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                return 60;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Based on Jason answer: I am getting the following error:

[image]

Second update based on Jason answer:
[image]

Third update based on Jason answer:
[image]

Comment: the reason you get the error is because one of your two lists will always be null.  I tried to explain this to you in your original question.

Comment: Jason, I have followed the numerous ways to fix, but no luck as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the two sets of data in the constructor, pass them as properties - this allows you to set them after the Source has been created, which is useful since you are getting the data asynchronously.

```
public class TableSource:UITableViewSource{

            public List<HTask> cTableItems;
            public List<HTask> aTableItems;


            string cellIdentifier="TableCell";
            private IViewController iv;

            public TableSource (IViewController vc)
            {
              aTableItems = new List<HTask>();
              cTableItems = new List<HTask>();
              iv=vc;
            }
```

Then create your Source **once** when you create the VC

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        TableView.Source = new TableSource(this);

        GInbox ();
        CInbox ();


    }
```

Finally, when you get the data don't recreate your Source, just update it with the data: (repeat the same thing for your other dataset)

```
    public void CInbox()
    {
        var client = new RestClient ("URL");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator ("admin", "admin");
        var request = new RestRequest ("other part URL");
        request.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //request.Method = (string)"GET";

        client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {

            cTasks = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HTask>> (response.Content);

            InvokeOnMainThread (() => {

                ((TableSource)this.TableView.Source).cTableItems = cTasks;
                TableView.ReloadData();

            });
        });
```

Comment: I'm not seeing all the code, but isn't `cTableItems` attached to the source and not the view itself.  Maybe something like `((TableSource)TableView.Source).cTableItems = cTasks;`?

Comment: Hi Jason, I have got a chance to test it this morning, however, please see my second update. it gives me the error. is it the following  ?        var TableViewSource = new TableSource(this);

Comment: Do you have a class named "Source"?  Or is it named "TableSource"?  Use whichever one is correct for your code.

Comment: I have TableSource class as follows `public class TableSource:UITableViewSource`

Comment: Hello Jason, I am also getting invalid casting error refer to my third update in the question.

Comment: Did #3 happen after you fixed #2?  Or at the same time?

Comment: It is not valid anymore, once I clean and rebuild again, then this error went away. Thanks a lot Jason.